# Merge 2 tables without repeat data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, left-join, window-functions

I need to merge the below tables.

**Table 1**

```
UserID |TopicName
1      |Topic1
1      |Topic2
2      |Topic1
2      |Topic2
2      |Topic3
```

**Table2**

```
UserID |Levelname
1      |level1
1      |level2
1      |level3
1      |level4
2      |level1
```

**Output**

```
UserID |TopicName|LevelName
1      |Topic1   |Level1
1      |Topic2   |Level2
1      |         |Level3
1      |         |Level4


TopicName|LevelName
1      |Topic1   |Level1
1      |Topic2   |Level2
1      |         |Level3
1      |         |Level4
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysq, oracle, sql-server....?

Comment: If this is mysql, `DISTINCT` is one option to return non-duplicate rows https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to match rows that have the same `userid`, based on their position. You could enumerate the rows in a subquery, then left join.

For this to work consistently, you need a column that defines the position of each row in each table - since nothing is showing in that regard in your data, I used the other column table - but you might want to change that.

```
select t2.userid, t1.topicname, t2.levelname
from (
    select t2.*, row_number() over(partition by userid order by topicname) rn
    from table2 t2
) t2
left join (
    select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by userid order by levelname) rn
    from table2 t1
) t1 on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.rn = t2.rn
```

You can add a `where` clause at the end of the query to filter on a given `userid`, as showned in your expected results:

```
where t2.userid = 1
```

If there might be "missing" rows in both tables, then a `full join` is a better pick:

```
select coalesce(t1.userid, t2.userid) userid, t1.topicname, t2.levelname
from (
    select t2.*, row_number() over(partition by userid order by topicname) rn
    from table2 t2
) t2
full join (
    select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by userid order by levelname) rn
    from table2 t1
) t1 on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: Thank You,GMB the second query is working perfectly